# Setting up a regexp for several situations

Tags: regex

I have a set of words in an array and i would like to get only the ones that match the regexp i apply to.

Let's say I have the following set of words:

friend
   fired
   fried
   afternoon
   affiliate
   activate
   staff
   neafe

and i need to apply a regexp that accomplish the following rules:

1.- One regexp that get only words that starts with 'f'.
2.- One regexp that get only words that ends with 'f'.
3.- One regexp that get only words that contains 'f'.
4.- One regexp that get only words that has one letter before 'f'.
5.- One regexp that get only words that has one letter after 'f'.

so, results for every case would be:

case 1
    friend
    fired
    fried

case 2
    staff

case 3
   friend
   fired
   fried
   afternoon
   affiliate
   staff
   neafe

case 4
   afternoon
   affiliate

case 5
   staff
   neafe

Need help please.

Comment: What do you need help with? Give it a go first, and then ask questions if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will all match only if the word fits the criteria you described for each case:

1. `^f.*`
2. `.*f$`
3. `f`
4. `^.f`
5. `f.$`

of course the input of each pattern MUST be a single word

Comment: Hi Diego, the first three work fine but the 4) and 5) do not. I'm using action script and apply the next regexp for 4) var patron:RegExp = new RegExp('f.', 'gi');  and include words whose second letter are not 'f'. Whats wrong?

Comment: @domoindal 4 should be `^.f.*`, 5 should be `.*f.$`

Comment: yes the description was not fully clear but the samples given was enough to guess the correct behavior. I corrected the points 4 and 5 to make them better fit the requirements. Anyway since you only need whatsoever match, there's no need for additional `.*` before and after. Glad Ghost solved your problem before I noticed.

Answer (score 0):

1. `^f.*`
2. `.*f$`
3. `f`
4. `.f.*`
5. `.*f.`

try this...

Comment: Hi Maulik, the first three work fine but the 4) and 5) do not. I'm using action script and apply the next regexp for 4) var patron:RegExp = new RegExp('.f.*', 'gi'); and include words whose second letter are not 'f'. Whats wrong?